# Custom Google profile URL

Tags: url, alias, profile

Now when google have changed their profiles in the last couple of days I cannot find any way of setting the profile URL. I have done this in the past but I had to create another account today and the feature is nowhere to be found. The instructions found in help @ google are describing the old profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it finally seems that google have launched something to deal with this.

http://glpl.us/

This service lets you create your own custom profile URL with this shortened format.
Take ours for example - now we have http://glpl.us/binalogue
Thanks google!

Comment: hmmm - correction. It is not a google product, but it sure does rock!

Answer (score 0):

For business pages, you have to go through a verification process:

- [how-to-get-a-custom-url-for-your-google-plus-business-page](http://corp.wishpond.com/google-plus-marketing-resources/how-to-get-a-custom-url-for-your-google-plus-business-page/)
- [verifying-your-google-plus-business-page](http://corp.wishpond.com/google-plus-marketing-resources/verifying-your-google-plus-business-page/)
- [google's verification request page](https://support.google.com/plus/contact/page_verification?hl=en&rd=1)

Update...now just this:
 - [Getting Started with Google+ Custom URLs](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en)